# How to check if string is only Numeric and AlphaNumeric and not character string?

Tags: c#, string, numeric, alphanumeric

I have a sample data in where have to determine whether the string is numeric or alpha numeric but not a simple character string.
for ex:

```
my data is:
123XY
12346
WEPXY
```

What is the condition that returns true for first two (alphanumeric and numeric) and returns false for pure character string?

Comment: Too ambiguous, "1E3" is numeric.

Comment: @HansPassant, in either case, the result would be a match.  It is *both* numeric and alphanumeric, depending on your interpretation.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384043.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression such as:

```
([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)|([0-9]+)
```

**Edit:**
Well, that had all sorts of problems... I couldn't figure this out with regex by itself, but was able to create a function that worked nicely:

```
private bool HasLettersAndNumbersOnly(string value)
{
    return !(Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$") || Regex.IsMatch(value, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"));
}
```

---

**Tests:**

123XY : True

12346 : True

XY123 : True

X123Y : True

x2c3g : True

2c3v4 : True

5c1=+ : False

WEPXY : False

Comment: I realize the parenthesis aren't required, but it helps me understand what the regular expression is doing...

Comment: That however requires the letters to follow the digits, and doesn't match for example `XY123`.

Comment: And also wouldn't work on X123Y...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression that only allows A-Z, a-z and 0-9, and uses a positive lookahead to require at least one digit:

```
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]+$");
```

Tests:

```
"123XY" : true
"12346" : true
"WEPXY" : false
"1abcd" : true
"abcd1" : true
"ab2cd" : true
"1abc2" : true
"1"     : true
"a"     : false
"1a"    : true
"a1"    : true
""      : false
```

Comment: Why not just look for a digit?  The regex \d is far, far simpler and achieves the correct results against the provided test data.

Comment: @Inuyasha: That doesn't accomplish the task to "determine whether the string is numeric or alpha numeric". A string like `"12-34"` would give a false positive.

Comment: A test string "12-34" was not provided in the test data.  The condition was that it isn't a simple character string and contains a numeric.  Our solutions need to fit the data provided, not data we dream up.  It is entirely possible "12-34" would *never* come up for testing.

Comment: @Inuyasha: In that case you could just use the expression `input <> "WEPXY"`. That will give you exactly the result you want for the given test data.

Comment: Since we're "dreaming up data", how about "123äää"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a method to do that use something like this you can check on either and have it return a True or false

```
public static bool IsOnlyNumbers(string strValidateString, bool boolCheck4LetterOrDigit)
{
    bool boolValidatePassed = false;
    switch (boolCheck4LetterOrDigit)
    {
      case  true:
        {
            if (strValidateString.All(Char.IsDigit))
            {
                boolValidatePassed = true;
            }
            break;
        }
      case false:
        {
            if (strValidateString.All(Char.IsLetter))
            {
                boolValidatePassed = false;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return boolValidatePassed;
}
```

Comment: That will return true for `WEPXY` too.

Comment: oops I wrote that quickly let me edit.. he could alter the example and change to work anyway he wants but basically if he utilizes the Char. methods he can find all that he needs and create a delegate, lambda, linq, for loop ect.. depending on what he wants to validate or check

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d");
string[] testData = new string[] { "123XY", "12346", "WEPXY" };
foreach (var s in testData)
{
    bool isMatch = r.IsMatch(s);
    Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}, Is match: {1}", s, isMatch);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Basically you just need to check that the string contains a numeric digit, right?  The regex '\d' matches any numeric digit.

The above code prints out:

> Data: 123XY, Is match: True
>   Data: 12346, Is match: True
>   Data: WEPXY, Is match: False